# how to group 160 UIButtons into sets of four

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to make a multi-question app. Let's take one test for example.
The test consists of 40 questions, and each question has four possible answers.

What's the best way of going about dragging four buttons over a question's four possible answers? How can I make it so when one of the multiple answers for a given question has been selected, the other three possible answers will be hidden?

Then apply the same thing to all the remaining questions.
im sure this is something really easy and simple, but iv spent weeks on it and cant work it out:(

example
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v3sz5s&s=5

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to learn to use your UIViewController to change the properties of the views. 
This is easy if you display one question at a time.

This will show you most of it.

http://www.sophia.org/ios-quiz-app-combined-tutorial

Comment: well its a test with 50 questions, each question have 4 possible answers. so i just attach a scroll view, set up a scoller, then drag the test as a image over and in the scroll view. then drag buttons on top of each of the answer.

Comment: You could, but it is far better to realize, you don't need to create individual UI elements for each question and answer set. You just reuse the same UILabel and UIButton instances, changing the displayed values and selected answers accordingly. This is fundamental MVC, Model View Controller separation, and reuse of the UI. Think of it like a template you fill out again and again.

Comment: that is exactly what i'm trying to achieve, but cannot figure out how to do it!